# Where to place rootfs of cubietruck?

Tags: debian

ive just bought a cubietruck and now installing cubian on it.i have 16gb microsd and 320gb hdd. im planning to use cubietruck as home media server with vpn and to install lamp on it.
But dont know where is better to place rootfs. flash memory has write cycles limit, but hdd is slower than flash memory.
What can you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Cubietruck has a NAND flash, the OS is installed here (If you burn NAND version images).
You can use your micrsd and hdd as data disk rather than root file system, microsd in the board is named /dev/mmcblk0, and hdd is named /dev/hda or /dev/sda, etc.

BTW, rootfs is packaged in the img file with bootloader, and other config files, if you real want to see them, (in NAND version), you just

- `mount /dev/nanda /mnt/config_file_and_kernel` to see config file and kernel
- `mount /dev/nandb /mnt/filesystem` to see you file system, the same as /